# Printf with general format specifier

Tags: c++, templates, formatting

I have created a c++ class using template t
I would like to know if there is any format specifier who can print or cast any value to its format

```
template <typename T>
void AssertAreEqual(T t_Expected,T t_Actual, int line){
if (t_Expected != t_Actual)
    printf("FAIL - Line < %d > - Expected value does not match with expected\tExpected: < %d > Actual < %d >\n",line,t_Expected,t_Actual); 
}
```

For example: I would like to have a global or general format specifier rather than %d in order to be able to print also strings or char*

Comment: Surely the whole point of format specifiers such as `%d` and `%s` is that they print integers and strings respectively, and do this by knowing the type of thing they can be applied to?

Comment: Why don't you want to use cout or stringstream?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka: Turtle Wax..

Comment: Sorry, I did a better job further down: `std::clog` and  `std:wclog` are streams you can use to get meaningful messages where they matter. `std:cerr` and `std::flush` will corrupt logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `printf` being variadic it relies on you to tell it what you want to print.  As far as I know there is no way to tell it to figure it out.

You can subvert the issue though using the [standard library's streams](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io). 
 The `operator <<` is overloaded for all built in types and the correct overload will be chose for you.  You can change the code to

```
template <typename T>
void AssertAreEqual(T t_Expected,T t_Actual, int line){
if (t_Expected != t_Actual)
    std::cerr << "FAIL - Line < " << line << " > - Expected value does not match with expected\tExpected: < " << t_Expected << " > Actual < " t_Actual << " >\n";
}
```

This also allows the code to work with any type that provides a `operator !=` and `operator <<`

Comment: Error messages should, in general, go to `std::cerr`.

Comment: Yes, or for interleaved logging, `std::clog` / `std::wclog`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I've upated to use `std::cerr`